# Plotting derivatives of B-splines

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, splines

I am trying to solve an electrodynamics problem numerically by using B-splines a basis function. Please don't ask me why, but if you really wanna know, [here is the assignment](http://www.atom.physto.se/~lindroth/comp08/Assignment6.pdf).

Using the following code, I have successfully plotted the B-spline basis functions in two dimensions, given the specific knot sequence and the respective x and y intervals.

```
knots = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 1, 1, 1, 1}
Plot3D[Evaluate[Table[BSplineBasis[{4, knots}, i, x], {i, 0, 3}]] Evaluate[
Table[BSplineBasis[{4, knots}, i, y], {i, 0, 3}]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

The corresponding plot looks like this:

[image]

Now I am trying to do the same for the second derivatives of the B-splines, using the following code:

```
knots = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 1, 1, 1, 1}
Plot3D[Evaluate[Table[D[BSplineBasis[{4, knots}, i, x], {x, 2}], {i, 0, 3}]] 
Evaluate[Table[D[BSplineBasis[{4, knots}, i, y], {y, 2}], {i, 0, 3}]],
{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

However, it does not work and produces an empty graph and lots of red error messages. I have tried several combinations of the D, Table and Evaluate operators, but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not doing the multiplication inside one `Table` ?

Comment: Is this what you want? knots = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 1, 1, 1, 1};
e1 = Evaluate[
   Table[D[BSplineBasis[{4, knots}, i, x], {x, 2}], {i, 0, 3}]];
e2 = Evaluate[
   Table[D[BSplineBasis[{4, knots}, i, y], {y, 2}], {i, 0, 3}]];
Plot3D[ e1*e2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]

Comment: @b.gatessucks: yes, both your answers solve my problem and give me the result I want!

Comment: @QuantumMathematica: yes, both your answers solve my problem and give me the result I want!

Comment: `Plot3D[Evaluate[Table[D[BSplineBasis[{4, knots}, i, \[FormalX]], {\[FormalX], 2}] D[BSplineBasis[{4, knots}, i, \[FormalY]], {\[FormalY], 2}] /. {\[FormalX] -> x, \[FormalY] -> y}, {i, 0, 3}]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]`

Comment: @J.M. I get the same if I don't use the `Formal` symbols and perform the replacement but simply use `x` and `y`. Is there any benefit in this case?

Comment: @Jonathan, I went for defensive programming in this case, since the formal symbols are guaranteed to never have any values assigned to them, thus preventing the all-too-common error of differentiating with respect to a constant.

Comment: @J.M. many thanks, that's a useful tip.

Answer (score 1):

```
knots = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 1, 1, 1, 1}; e1 = 
Evaluate[Table[
D[BSplineBasis[{4, knots}, i, x], {x, 2}], {i, 0, 3}]]; e2 = 
Evaluate[Table[
D[BSplineBasis[{4, knots}, i, y], {y, 2}], {i, 0, 3}]]; Plot3D[
e1*e2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[
  Table[D[BSplineBasis[{4, knots}, i, \[FormalX]], {\[FormalX], 2}] D[
      BSplineBasis[{4, knots}, i, \[FormalY]], {\[FormalY], 
       2}] /. {\[FormalX] -> x, \[FormalY] -> y}, {i, 0, 3}]], {x, 0, 
  1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[image]